# Basis for unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

In math SE for what reasons do questions normally meet with nil responses, subject-wise?

Could it be so for being outside normal limits of some feature, in some manner...lack of clarity, topic too advanced, too obsolete, very uncommon, or what marks it for lack of general interest even when kept indefinitely open?

Of course I risk this one too could belong to that open set.

Comment: The answers to this question will have a strong time-dependent component, and will also be quite opinion-based. Moreover, I don't feel like we should be creating an atmosphere where we say "questions about X are hopeless on MSE, you might as well not ask them". That way, it will be a self-fulfilling prophecy, which I would consider a bad thing.

Comment: Does it make sense to close questions on meta as "primarily opinion-based"? Isn't meta where we thrash out our opinions on topics concerning main?

Comment: @Gerry Even though we are on meta level, it can still be that questions cannot be answered properly and are not a good fit. I contend this is such a question, and I don't think it's beneficial to MSE to discuss this. Any proper answers will boil down to a digestion of the [good question thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351). The opinion-based reason seemed most applicable, although I understand your second thoughts about the exact word choice.

Comment: Oh dear, what is it about?.. I was just making a neutral inquiry about things. I have not commented on anything, expressed no opinion in anyway ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topic matters to some extent but per Lord_Farin the most constructive approach is to focus on actionable reasons why a question might get less attention that it should.

When does a question get *answered* on math.se? All of the following have to be true:

1. An answerer understands your question;
2. An answerer believes they can figure out the solution in a reasonable amount of time;
3. An answerer is positively inclined towards providing that solution.

Questions that run afoul of these criteria are less likely to be answered. How can you avoid this fate? Some tips:

1. Avoid walls-o-text that will cause a reader's eyes to glaze over, *especially* large paragraphs of un-Latexed math. Use a clear question title, appropriate tags, and make the question you're asking stand out in the question body: don't bury the question in the middle of extended calculation or tangential discussion. Define your notation if there's any chance of confusion: a potential answerer might have learned from a different text than you, or might be from a completely different field.
2. Don't ask multiple questions at once. Don't ask too broad of a question that will require a very long answer (although sometimes you can get away with this if you later offer a bounty). Keep the question self-contained. Include figures and diagrams. Include context about where the problem came from, to give the answerer a hint about what a solution might look like (or whether one is expected to exist at all).
3. Be polite and professional. Volunteers are doing *you* a favor by answering your question: act accordingly and make people *want* to help you. Avoid appearing pushy or lazy; there's nothing like titling your question "HELPP!!!!! NEED ANSWER IMMEDIATELY!!!!" to guarantee no answer and tons of down and close votes. Don't just copy-paste a homework question (or worse, post grainy hard-to-read iPhone scans of the problem set!) with no indication you have made any effort to solve it yourself.